# I need to verify whether a label "Annuitant" and its value " RPD" is present or not using parent class

Tags: ruby, capybara

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <span>Annuitant:</span>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
<span id="annuitant">
RPD                 
</span>
</div>
```

Xpath code that i used previously

```
  findXpath=page.find('label', text: workbook.cell(j,k), :match => :prefer_exact).path 

  splitXpath=(findXpath.split("/")) #splitting xpath

 ##Xpath manipulation to get the xpath of "RPD"
      count1=splitXpath.count
      value1=splitXpath.at(count1-3)
      value=splitXpath.at(count1-2)
      labelNum=value1.match(/(\d+)/)
      i=0
      elementNum=labelNum[1].to_i+1 

      for maxnum in 1..splitXpath.count-4
        elementXpath=elementXpath + "/" + splitXpath[maxnum]
      end

      elementXpath=elementXpath + "/div[" + elementNum.to_s + "]" + "/"+ value
      elementXpath=elementXpath + "/" + splitXpath.at(count1-1)
      finalElementXpath=elementXpath.sub("label","span")# obtained the xpath of RPD
      if (workbook.cell(j+1,k) == (find(:xpath, finalElementXpath).native.text)) # verifying the value RPD is present
```

Can I use parent class and verify whether "Annuitant" is present and also to check whether Annuitant value is "RPD". Please help me to write a code for this in ruby capybara

Comment: What do you mean by "parent class" in the example you've given?

Comment: @Tom Walpole : I meant,  can I use the immediate  div class ="col-sm-3" or any other upper div class(there are many div class, i just mentioned only the immediate div class in the example)  to verify whether  annuitant is present and it has the value "RPD".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `assert_selector` to check if the selector has the text you want. See below:

```
page.assert_selector('#annuitant', :text => 'RPD', :visible => true)
```

Comment: @ Mesut Güneş : Thanks this worked when specifying as '# annuitant' and , :text as "RPD". I need to verify around 150 text and its values in the similar way. I'm using excel sheet to have the values      cell(0,0) = Annuitant , cell (1,0) =  RPD. This is the fashion I ihave used in excel sheet. Is there a way to take values from excel and verify.

Comment: @RPD you can do it in a loop with checking text

Comment: @RPD you should ask another question with new code and accept the  answer since your original question was different.

Answer (score 0):

You can scope Capybara's finders/matchers to any element by either calling them on an element or using within(element) ...

In this case you'd want to scope to at least one level higher in your html document so that both elements you are interested in are contained by the element you're scoping too.  Also the class 'col-sm-3' would be a bad choice because it is not going to be unique to these elements.  Another thing this comes down to is how rigorous does your check need to be, do you actually need to check the structure of the elements or do you just need to verify the text appears next to each other on the page.  If the latter something like

```
element = find('<selector for parent/grandparent of both elements>') # could also just be `page` if the text is unique
expect(element).to have_text('Annuitant: RPD')
```

if you do actually need to verify the structure things get more complicated and you would need to use XPath

```
expect(element).to have_selector(:xpath, './/div[./span[text()="Annuitant:"]]/following-sibling::div[1][./span[normalize-space(text())="RPD"]]')
```

Comment: @ Tom Walpole : I need to verify the structure as well. So used xpath previously. But it took more time identifying  the xpath and manipulating. I need to verify around 400+ values and texts in this way. I have edited my question above with the code I used for xpath.

Comment: @RPD that code doesn't match the HTML you have there at all - (no label elements) and it's not very clear what you're trying to do. As I guess from taking bits of that code and your html you want something like -  `if  page.has_selector?(:xpath, ".//div[./span[text()=\"#{workbook.cell(j,k)}:\"]]/following-sibling::div[1][./span[normalize-space(text())=\"#{workbook.cell(j+1,k)}\"]]") #then do something`  - If that's not what you're trying to do then you should create a new question where you fully describe the problem to be solved and provide real complete data/html